# Tracking page in user profile

Tags: feature-request, questions, tracking, notifications

At the bottom of each question you can now ask to be notified via email if answer are posted. What I would prefer is a tracking page that is like recent but show these question that are being tracked in a page in my user profile. Like the info but not a big fan of the email option.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Detail Recent Favorite changes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83292/detail-recent-favorite-changes)

Answer (score 1):

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/recent/32958

Does that not do it for you?

Comment: I think what he wants is a central place to see which questions he's tracking via email

Comment: But he said he didn't want to use email!

Comment: I think rex is looking for something like the /users/recent/ thing, but only for specific questions

Comment: @Ian: ...then I have no idea what he's getting at :-)

Comment: instead of getting the info via email I would like to see what is contained in the emails in a page on my user profile. When I am on the site it would be nice to know when their is new activity on questions that I am monitoring. I am a big fan of having all of my info in one place.