# New favorites profile tab problems

Tags: support, recent-activity, bookmarks, favorites-tab, activity-dropdown

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Recent favorite changes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83292/recent-favorite-changes)

The old (and beloved) Recent Activity page showed whether the activity on a favorite was an answer or comment, and linked you to it.  The new favorites page in the profile only points you to a question.  So in a busy question, it can be quite hard to find what was added.

Also, the Recent button in the favorites tab on the profile is a sort, not a filter, which isn't near as useful for trimming the amount of data down that you have to deal with.  The old functionality of showing what was new since you last looked at it was much more functional.