# What is the best way to be notified when a specific question (not my own) is answered?

Tags: discussion

What is the best way to be notified when a specific question (not my own) is answered?  I've tried setting these questions as "favorites", but there doesn't seem to be a good way to then follow the favorites.  The "Favorites" link when I hover over my name just indicates which questions I've *added* as favorites, not when those questions are updated/answers.

Is there another / better way?

Comment: There is [a way](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88127/what-does-a-small-asterisk-in-the-favorites-tab-in-my-user-profile-mean/88252#88252) to figure out how to check which answer is update on your favorited questions.

Comment: They haven't fixed favorite notification yet, but it will still somewhat indicate that your question has been answered.

Comment: @You, I looked at that view.  It just seems to give me a list of questions I have favorited recently.

Comment: @Lance, so there is something in the works for favorite notification?

Comment: @Marcie, "recently" is not that you have favorited recently but "added" is. recently is ordered by recent activities on the posts you favorited.

Comment: @Marcie, they say there is, but haven't seen hide nor hair of anything yet.

Comment: @You, yes, but if I added it recently and there is no answer yet, it still shows up at the top of Recent, which doesn't help me.

Comment: @Lance, ok thanks, I will keep my fingers crossed!

Comment: Vote on these to help speed things up: [Favorite1](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83292/recent-favorite-changes), [Favorite2](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83652/new-favorites-profile-tab-problems-closed).