# Background color missing for changes on favorites tab

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, user-interface, design

Okay, this is somewhat persnickety.

Notifications of changes in the reputation, activity, responses, and favorites categories are indicated by this blue "bullet":

[image: white asterisk on a blue background]

The changed or added items within the tabs have a slightly different background color, (`#FFFFDD`<sup>1</sup>), which looks like this:

[image: yellow background for recently changed posts]

**Except** for those on the favorites tab, which just have the plain white background.

Could the different background color be added for changed favorites?

<sub>1) For clarity purposes, I changed the different background color in the image above to `#FFFFCC`.</sub>

Comment: I don't see it... Maybe my notebook's monitor is improperly calibrated. Can you post a screenshot demonstrating the *difference*?

Comment: See also [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83343/adding-favorites-to-the-stack-exchange-global-inbox/88595#88595).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Detail Recent Favorite changes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83292/detail-recent-favorite-changes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems this feature request is now implemented since the deploy of the new redesigned profile pages.