# How to see what changed in a favorite?

Tags: support, bookmarks

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Detail Recent Favorite changes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83292/detail-recent-favorite-changes)

When I click on my user name it says I have 3 favorites (changes, I presume) today. So, I click on favorites and it takes me to faves sorted by recent. Good so far. I click on the second question and can't find anything that's changed within the past *several* days. I must be doing something wrong. How do I find out which favorites changed and--even better--*what exactly* changed?

[image]

Comment: They broke it when they moved to the dropdown, and it hasn't been fixed yet.

Comment: So there's no way to know what, in the favorite, changed?

Comment: Not yet, right now it's all manual scanning.  It used to work better in the past.

Comment: That's what I thought, which is why I was so puzzled.

Answer (score 4):

**EDIT 2:** See Hendrik's comments below -- it was due to the three new comments on the question not made by Daniel.

---

I have 1 favorite change in the dropdown today here on Meta, the tooltip says "1 new answer or comment on your favorites today".  So I would *guess* your says `3` due to (1) the new comments on Greg Hewgill's answer, (2) the new comment on Layke's answer, and (3) the new comments on the question itself; those are the only new actions within the past 20 hours (the current UTC day).  But I don't know for sure.  Maybe it only counts 1 change per question, so actually 3 of your favorites got commented on or something.

---

**EDIT:** The below doesn't make sense in the context of the screenshot.

[The question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7434407/is-there-any-single-article-f-3-0-overview) changed:

> edited Sep 15 at 20:26

The favorites page says Sept. 15th, so it's accurate.

The `3` you saw on the favorites tab was how many favorites that have changed since the last time you looked at the favorites tab, not the number that have changed today.

Comment: Matthew: Sorry, the second question.

Comment: @Daniel Updated my answer.

Comment: My profile says 3 favorites have changed _today_. I assumed that would be the top 3 in the list. How do I know which ones changed _today_?

Comment: The column header says "today". That's weird if your answer is correct.

Comment: @Daniel Could you add a screenshot to the question? I'm not seeing that.

Comment: I added a screenshot.

Comment: @Daniel Ah, now that's different.  I would *guess* that's due to (1) new comments on Greg Hewgill's answer, (2) new comment on Layke's answer, and (3) new comments on the question itself.  But I don't know for sure.

Comment: I think you're looking at the wrong question. Here's the question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7434407/is-there-any-single-article-f-3-0-overview (#2 by recent)

Comment: @Daniel I think the Favorites tab only shows changes that are more substantial than comments, whereas the dropdown on your username includes changes that are merely comments.  So that question actually isn't involved at all.  Obviously this is extremely broken so who even knows?  I'm going to support the feature request linked as the duplicate.

Comment: @Matthew: You got that wrong. You don't get favorite notifications for comments on _answers_, only for comments on the _questions_ and for _new answers_. My guess is that the 3 meant three new comment on [the question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7520569). (Ping, @Daniel `:-)`)

Comment: @Hendrik I thought there were 4 new comments, maybe I miscounted.

Comment: @Matthew: Daniel's own comment doesn't seem to count. Check it out yourself - favorite this question and leave a comment to the question! (And wait some time, it may take some time for the favorite notification to appear in the dropdown.) I'll also leave a comment.