# How can we follow answers here via Stack Overflow itself?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Subscribing to questions and comments that don't belong to you](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45360/subscribing-to-questions-and-comments-that-dont-belong-to-you)

Sometimes when I notice an interesting question I would like to "follow" it, and receive new answers. I know that we can get the RSS question feed, but whether we can organize them just here without using something like Google Reader.

Answer (score 3):

You can mark questions with the star, which IIRC means that you get notifications of new answers.

Comment: This is a quite subtle form of notification - it shows up as a number in the "favorites" line of the supercollider, and in the "favorites" tab of your user page. Nothing like an inbox notification.

Comment: @PaŭloEbermann I entirely agree. There's still an [open feature request to add more detail to the **favorites** tab](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/83292). Upvote it, put a bounty on it, spread the word. :)