# Implement the "very interesting questions" basket

Tags: feature-request

I'm not talking about the interesting tags, nor the "favorites" (yellow star) questions.

Very often I read questions that I am interested in, that I can't answer but I would be interested in the answer. Yes, I know I can mark them as favourites, but then to show them I have to go to my account page and click the favorites tab, then click on the question to see if there are new answers.

I would like a different thing, some sort of a "put this in the quick basket" button, near the question title (no need to even open the question), so that I am notified when gradually the "basketed" questions get answers, or when an answer is selected.

[image: notification area]

Comment: The inbox is already rather busy. I personally find the favorites implementation as it stands to be more than enough for this.

Comment: A similar discussion around the usefulness of favorites (and whether they should be nixed or expanded on): [Is the favorite questions system impractical?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123898/is-the-favorite-questions-system-impractical)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Counter-proposal:  Show me when one of my favorited questions gets answered.

Oh, wait.  [This already exists.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/403335/vulkanino?tab=favorites#vulkanino?tab=favorites&sort=activity&_suid=1331050201150046244299151418355)

That said, it would be nice if new answers on favorites showed up in your inbox.

Comment: Do you mean email notification? not what I'm asking. And your answer is not constructive because you don't specify how.

Comment: Click the link...

Comment: the link just shows your favs.

Comment: Click it again. I changed it to your account's `Favorites/Activity`. Look at the time stamps along the right hand side. It's a list of all of your favorites that have had recent activity, newest to oldest.

Comment: mm ok, I can live with this. I am not **notified**, I have to go there, as I said.

Answer (score 0):

Why stop at just one extra list of "bookmarked" questions? Why not go whole-hog and just beef up the Favorite functionality into a full-fledged system with nested folders of favorite questions that users can organize how they like? Oh, wait, that functionality already exists in almost all browsers...

`</devils-advocate>`

That said, having this sort of functionality would be nice because so much more instrumentation could be wrapped around it that raw bookmarked URLs couldn't have. This *does* seem a bit out of scope for the site itself, however, and would be better suited to a plugin.

Comment: While I understand the resistance to implementing new features  because it's not easy, requires a lot of work and lately: who cares? - nonetheless in this right case I think it would speed up the question reading a lot, at least for me. I don't use favorites much, that really adds little to the browsers implementation.

Comment: I think the resistance is more along the lines of "We'd rather implement things that are closer to the core mission of the system", but I agree that such a feature would be useful. My system for this right now is to simply leave an interesting question open in a tab and come back to it in a little while (could be a few hours, or a few days). If my browser crashes and I lose that tab, oh well. If nothing interesting happens when I come back or I get bored waiting for something interesting, I just walk away. I'd rather _not_ have to do things this way, but it works OK.

Comment: that is exactly how I do, and I end up having >20 tabs open, which I refresh in turn.

Comment: 1.) The auto-refresh plugin for Chrome is a god-send (you can also select multiple tabs at once and refresh them all) 2.) I usually have a total of 100+ tabs open across 7 desktops on my machine at any given point in time, so adding ten more tabs here or there doesn't phase me. I don't know what I would do if I had a ram-limited machine.