# When Do I get favorite notification?

Tags: discussion, tag-watching, bookmarks

I see my favorites tab in profile got notification, but Even If I click newest I don't know what has happened there.  I don't know which one got added as favorite..

Comment: "I dont know which one got added as favorite.." How can you not know? These are *your* favorite questions.

Comment: I dont know,  I am getting notification in my favorites tab always and I dont know why and what has changed there..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You get favorites notifications when something **changes** in your favorites, not because a favorite is added.

The favorited questions with changes will be highlighted, in the same way that questions in your favorite tags are in other question lists.  To see what changed, click on the date link next to the question, which leads to the last action.

Comment: Thank you so much..  From both the answers I got a clear answer..  I was imagining that any one adding that question as favorite it is getting hi-lighted.. Thanks once again..:)

Answer (score 2):

The highlighted favorites are the ones that have been modified.  If you want to know how, you have to click into them, and then scroll the entire post looking for recent dates.  There is a [feature-request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83292/detail-recent-favorite-changes) to add more detail, but it hasn't got any traction yet.

Comment: Or you could click the date link next to the question.  It looks like it's about the question's author, but is actually about whatever bumped the post.

Comment: @blahdiblah, I'm intrigued that that might work, but will have to wait for the next change to see if it works.  And does it work for comments, questions, answers and edits.  You might want to put an answer on the feature-request to that effect.

Comment: Ok this is the answer,  the favorite get highlighted.  If there is any edits in the Favorited post..  I was thinking I will get the notification when a new guy adding the same post as his favorite..:) thank you so much..